# How to use interceptor on a event listener in nestjs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When receiving an event on a method with the annotation `@EventPattern`, how can get the message content using an interceptor?

The listener:

```
@EventPattern(PUB_SUB_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)
@UseInterceptors(MyCustomInterceptor)
async processMessage(receivedMessage: Message): Promise<void> {}
```

The interceptor:

```
intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler<any>,
): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const { data } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body as Message;
}
```

The `context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body` should give me the message content? The request itself was not a `http` request (?)

Answer (score 0):

So long as `@EventPattern()` is from `@nestjs/microservices` and not some other package, you should be able to use `context.switchToRpc().getData()` to get the data about the request. As you're using an RPC context, you should make the `ExecutionContext`'s helper methods aware of that by using `switchToRpc()`. Technically, all of the`switchTo*()` methods are minor helpers, as everything is held within the `args` array, but the methods do make it easier to read what's happening rather than just `context.getArgByIndex(1)` or whatever index you need.